# Can someone explain me PHP Iterator?

Tags: php, iterator

I was trying to get an overview and understand PHP Iterator through the examples on this official page. Can someone explain it to me? As to what is it used for and how are the results computed as shown on the page.

The link to PHP Iterator: http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Comment: "Please explain" is not a question. We can help, but you should be more specific, tell, what you do not understand.

Comment: @Voitcus: I was having trouble understanding it. There wasn't need of any downvotes. I have clearly mentioned that `"what is it used for and how are the results computed as shown on the page"`

Comment: OK, but I haven't voted you down.

Comment: @Voitcus: My apologies then. :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A PHP Iterator is essentially a seekable object. Its main property is that it goes through `foreach` with flying colours and behaves exactly as it should. Instead of doing something like:

```
foreach (myFunction() as $v) {
   doSomethingWith($v);
}
```

You can create an Iterator (Seekable, Rewindable etc) to simplify the work, and also bind anything else you might want in there, allowing you to only do the work once.

Creating an Iterator object and calling `foreach ($object as $r)` does the following (in order):

1. Rewinds the iterator (calls `$object->rewind()`)
2. Checks if the current op is valid with `$object->valid()`, terminates the loop if needed
3. If the loop is not terminated, returns the current item and key with `$object->current()` and `$object->key()` and moves to the next object using `$object->next()`
4. GOTO step 2

Pretty simple structure, only to be expected as it is a SPL interface. Effectively, its only purpose is to allow your object to go through `foreach`. Nothing more, nothing less. You can use them for a variety of stuff - I used one recently to simplify the process of looping through messages yielded from an IMAP server (and to make sure I only did the processing once).

There are some Iterators already defined in PHP - my favourite is possibly `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`, which dramatically eases up the burden of having to recursively walk through directories.

Hope this helped. Any questions, feel free to comment and I'll elaborate.